# sql group all value

Tags: sql, mariadb

in sql, mariadb, i want to group many column like :

i have this in sql:

when i run this command : `select * from table` or when in use `group by` :

result:

```
a b
a c
a d
a e
```

i want to `regroup` all a and b c d e like this:

```
a b,c,d,e
```

thanks for any information

Answer (score 2):

if you want only a comma separated  result  you could try  using concat and group_concat

assuming col1  contain the a value and col2 the b,c,d,e value

```
   select concat(col1, ', ',group_concat(col2))
   from  my_table  
   group by col1
```

Answer (score 1):

In MariaDB, you can use `union` and [`group_concat()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/group_concat/):

```
select group_concat(mycol order by mycol) res
from (
    select col1 mycol from mytable
    union select col2 from mytable
) x
```

`union` generates a new resultset while removes the duplicate values across columns. Then `group_concat()` flattens the results as a comma-separated list. The `order by` option of `group_concat()` lets you determine the order of returned values. This gives you a comma-separated list of all distinct values in columns `col1` and `col2`.

If you want all values of `col2` grouped by `col1`, then it is different:

```
select col1, group_concat(col2 order by col2)
from mytable
group by col1
```